# What kind of insect eggs are these (found in Malaysia)?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, eggs

What kind of eggs are these?

Found outside on a window, when I removed them via scraping, whitish oozy fluid came out. I've seen this before but they've been appearing more frequently, always appear in a straight line and are brown.

This is in Malaysia, in South East Asia. More specifically Johor. The entire line measured about 1 inch, and in terms of individual egg size, 0.3 inches.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This eggs belong to ***[Mictis profana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mictis_profana)*** which is a species of insect in the family [Coreidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreidae) known by the common names crusader bug and holy cross bug. It is distributed in Australia, Indonesia, and the Indo-Pacific.

[image]